# AngularJS Dependency injection failure - Drag&Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a Drag&Drop system.
I've found an amazing one :
http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested
Github:
https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/issues

Now, it says load "dndLists" into my Dependency -
So my app looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('clarus_app', ['ngRoute'], ['dndLists'] );
```

but then it crashes.

angular.js:116 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module clarus_app due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

No idea what I'm doing wrong.
The controller the page uses looks like this:
`app.controller("logCtrl", ['$scope','$location','$http', function($scope, $location, $http){`

Any help? any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different array arguments for module dependency and only want one array containing all dependencies

Change

```
var app = angular.module('clarus_app', ['ngRoute'], ['dndLists'] );
```

To

```
var app = angular.module('clarus_app', ['ngRoute','dndLists'] );
                                      // ^^ single array of dependent module names
```